# "preventDefault()" или "return false"?

Tags: javascript

Не раз замечал, что в различных кодах используют то `preventDefault()`, то `return false`. И это касается, как маленьких, так и больших проектов.

По старинке, я привык использовать во всём `return false`, но недавно задумался: может `preventDefault()` лучше чем return? Почему его так часто используют?

Так всё же что лучше использовать: `preventDefault()` или `return false`?

```js
var type = null;

for(var i = 0; i <= 1; i++){
  document.querySelectorAll('[name="type"]')[i].onclick = function() {
    type = this.value;
  };
};

document.querySelector('a').onclick = function(e) {
  if(type == 'pd'){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Прервано функцией preventDefault()!');
  }else if(type == 'rf'){
    alert('Прервано функцией return false!');
    return false;
  };
};
```

```css
body {font-family: arial;}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="pd"> - preventDefault;
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="rf"> - return false;
</p>
<a href="javascript:alert('Произошёл переход по ссылке!');">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1357118/2110496

Comment: @vp_arth, нифига там 2300 лайков у ответа) Ещё и +500 получил.. от меня такого не дождётесь :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return false` из *обработчика события jQuery* так же, как вызов обоих `e.preventDefault` и `e.stopPropagation` у переданного [jQuery.Event события.](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

- `e.preventDefault()` остановит обработку события по умолчанию,
- `e.stopPropagation()` остановит всплытие события по DOM
- `return false` остановит их оба.
- `e.stopImmediatePropagation` предотвращает всплытие всех подобных событий (полезно, когда на элементе есть несколько обработчиков одного события)

В обычных (не-jQuery) обработчиках событий `return false` не запрещает всплывание(bubbling) события.

Также `return false;` в ванильном js не запрещает обработку события по умолчанию из `addEventListener` обработчиков.
Он работает только из `el.onclick` хендлеров.

Source: [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/)

[**Any benefit to using event.preventDefault() over "return false" to cancel out an href click?**](http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg71371.html)

---

[Вольный перевод ответа с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151)

#### Вывод:

В jquery - полезнее `return false`
В vanillaJS - лучше его не использовать, он работает только с onclick-like обработчиками.

---

*В IE8 и ниже необходимо заменить `stopPropagation` на `cancelBubble`, а `preventDefault` на `return false;`*

---

#### Демонстрация

Третья ссылка совершает переход несмотря на `return false`

```js
document.getElementById('a1').addEventListener('click', function(e){
 console.log('preventDefault - clicked');
 e.preventDefault();
});

document.getElementById('a2').onclick = function(){
 console.log('return false from onclick');
 return false;
};

document.getElementById('a3').addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log('return false - clicked');
 return false;
})
```

```html
<a id="a1" href="/">preventDefault</a><br/>
<a id="a2" href="/">return false from onclick</a><br/>
<a id="a3" href="/">return false</a><br/>
```

Comment: А если использовать и то, и то; что будет? :)

Comment: Где использовать? Что и то, и то? preventDefault и return false? return false после preventDefault не имеет смысла. Не в жуквери, разумеется.

Comment: stopImmediatePropagation делает немного не то, что вы написали. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: @PavelMayorov, `Если один из этих слушателей вызовет event.stopImmediatePropagation() тогда события оставшихся слушателей вызваны не будут.` Я ведь ровно то же самое написал. По крайней мере имел в виду)

Answer (score 4):

[Хорошая статья](http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2013/05/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-preventdefault-stoppropagation-%D0%B8-stopimmediatepropagation/).

- Если вы всего лишь хотите предотвратить действие браузера по умолчанию, то вам следует использовать [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) метод.
- [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), который останавливает всплытие (bubbling) события к родительским элементам.
- `return false` может отменить действие браузера при использовании в `DOM Level 0` (`inline`-обработчик).
- [`stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) запрещает вызов всех остальных обработчиков даже на текущем событии.

```js
// Отменяем действие браузера, в данном случае - переход по ссылке
document.querySelector('#preventDefault').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.info('preventDefault: %s', this.href);
});

// При клике на span - меняем цвет
// Можно убедится в этом кликом по тексту
document.querySelector('#stopPropagationSpan').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  this.style.color = 'green';
});
// А вот клик по ссылке не даст всплыть событию до span, смены цвета не будет
document.querySelector('#stopPropagationLink').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault(); // Просто для демонстрации, если убрать - переход будет
  console.info('stopPropagation: %s', this.href);
});

// Навешано 2 обработчика
// Без stopImmediatePropagation будет смена цвета с зелёного (green) на синий (blue)
// Однако, мы заблокировали дальнейшие обработчики, поэтому цве будет только зелёный
document.querySelector('#stopImmediatePropagation').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault(); // Просто для демонстрации, если убрать - переход будет
  this.style.color = 'green';
});
document.querySelector('#stopImmediatePropagation').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  this.style.color = 'blue';
});
```

```html
<a href='normalLink'>Обычная ссылка, переход будет.</a><br /><br />
<a href='returnFalse' onclick='this.style.color = "black"; return false;'>Перехода нет, блокируется через "return false".</a><br /><br />
<a href='preventDefault' id='preventDefault'>preventDefault()</a><br /><br />
<span id='stopPropagationSpan'>
  <a href='stopPropagation' id='stopPropagationLink'>stopPropagation()</a><br />
  А тут клик отловится через span!
</span><br /><br />
<a href='stopImmediatePropagation' id='stopImmediatePropagation'>stopImmediatePropagation()</a>
```

Comment: В том-то и дело, что нифига он в vanillaJS не заменяет. Он вообще ничего не делает из addEventListener обработчиков

Comment: 1) Что "не заменяет". 2) Работает, что Вы :)

Comment: Добавил демо в свой ответ. То, что вы написали относится только к обработчикам jQuery

Comment: @vp_arth, ох, Фома неверующий, посмотри - всё работает.

Comment: ты о чём вообще? Я про `return false заменяет вызов методов выше`

Comment: Мы сейчас в вопросе `preventDefault vs return false;` на минуточку

Comment: @vp_arth, действительно :) Слишком молод, чтобы работать с `DOMLevel0`, спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault()
```

По w3c это стандартный метод для отмены события.

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation